# Load php query in div onclick

Tags: php, mysql

I'm loading photos from database with mysql query. For default it load data from database with pagination.

```
<div class="col-md-10 bg col-md-push-2  ">
    <div class="align_center  gallery">
        <?php
            include "anj.php";
            $sql =  'SELECT * FROM new_photos ;
            /* function anjaan content code for loading photos .*/
            anjaan($sql);
            }
        ?>
    </div>
    <div class=" align_center ">
        <div class=" col-md-12 pagination gallery">
            <?php    
                    echo $paginationctrl;
                    ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Now I want when user click a button data should change with this

```
<?php
    include "anj.php";
    $sql =  'SELECT * FROM new_photos WHERE weight BETWEEN 10 AND 15';
    anjaan($sql);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Php is just server side, so i think u only will have two options.

1 - On click reload de page and send a post or get params to the application usign form and then load the page with the new query.

2 - If u want to do not reload te page, will be better to send an Ajax request to server side with JavaScript and then bring and replace the old content for the new one.

Comment: how to use 1 method .

Comment: i tried 1 method but pagination load content on second page from else query.

Comment: In 1 method, u submit a post by form and in the server side (controler maybe?) you verify if some post have been submited, in that case you change the default sql for the new one you want. Then just render again you view with the new data.